# Problem while creating an item of a model class

Tags: android, arrays, list, kotlin, interface

I am trying to create a list using an interface in order to use this list inside fragment. But problem occurs while creating the instances of model class. All code works without any problem if I don't implement an interface and do all that inside fragment class. But I am trying to make the job by using interface, which is the method I am not familiar with. It is certain that I am making mistake inside interface. Maybe about the initialization of the "list" object or "item" object.

My model class is this:

```
class MyModelClass(
    var title: String,
    var images: ArrayList<String>
)
```

My interface is this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    val mcontext: Context
    val list: ArrayList<MyModelClass>

 fun getList(): List<MyModelClass> {
    for (i in 0 until xarray.length()) {
          val item = MyModelClass(title, images)  //The values for title and images come from Json parsing result. They give correct values when I print them seperately, but when I create item from Exhibit class using them, then problem occurs
                list += item
                println("item = " + item)   //com.bb.App.MyModelClass@a28b423  //This is not the correct list item
                println("list = " + list)  //list = []
    }
}
```

Giving a little detailed explanation will be appreciated if possible since I am not familiar with interfaces. Any ideas?

Ok, thanks to whom gave me ideas, I solved the problem, only problem was about the initialization of list value inside fragment.

Comment: _then problem occurs_ what's the problem? what is `xarray`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia xarray is a working arr,ay, array created by reading json content from file. No problem about json conversion, therefore I didn't write that irrelative code

Comment: In getExhibitList where does "title" and "images" come from?
Can you even add an item to a list using "+=" sign?
You are printing "item" which is instance of Exhibit. That's working fine. If you want to see values of title or images you need to print them individually like:
println("item = " + item.title)
Printing the list would not work either.
Where is that list being initialized anyway?

Comment: Yes you are right, it prints item.title correctly, but when I want to print "list", shouldn't it create output like [[title1, imageArray], [title2, imageArray2], [title3, ima....]]. It gives output of [] this. Empty array

Comment: += sign and all other code works without any problem if I don't implement an interface and do all that inside fragment class. The problem is I am trying to make the job by using interface, which is the method I am not familiar with. I don't know how to initialize list inside interface. Can you help with more detail as if I am a newbie?